# How to make a perl regex and references part of the matching string in the regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to make a perl regex that references something it finds in the query on the fly. I've never tried to make a regex like this, and am not even sure it is possible. Here's my current regex:

```
$sample =~ s/(+|-)[1][a-zA-Z]{1}//g;
```

This is meant to take my `$sample` variable as a query, and delete any section of the string that matches something like `+1X` with nothing. However, the number defines the number of following characters, all of which I want removed.

So, if my string is `foo+3xzybar`, the regex should return `foobar`. How can I grab the matching number in the regex and use it to quantify the number of letters to match? Instead of writing explicit cases like this:

```
$sample =~ s/(+|-)[1][a-zA-Z]{1}//g;
$sample =~ s/(+|-)[2][a-zA-Z]{2}//g;
$sample =~ s/(+|-)[3][a-zA-Z]{3}//g;
$sample =~ s/(+|-)[4][a-zA-Z]{4}//g;
```

I want to make something like this:

```
$sample =~ s/(+|-)[(0-9)][a-zA-Z]{($1)}//g; #(0-9) is meant to match and save the digit in $1
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In pure regex, you can't. You must extract the integer and then use it to determine the number of characters.

Comment: I don't think you can have something that's found by an early part of the regex make structural modifications to the remainder of the regex. You could try `s/(?:[-+])([\d])[a-zA-Z]{\1}//g` but I'd be pretty surprised if it worked.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, actually it can be done with Perl RE, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use a match to breakup the string, and then reassemble it a line later:

```
$sample =~ /(.*?)[+\-]([0-9])([a-zA-Z]+)(.*)/ ;
$sample= $1 . substr($3, $2) . $4 if $2 ;
```

So you get everything before the +N, then use +N to offset into the letters right beyond, then tack anything else on afterwards.  Repeat as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

When one is willing to use fancy (and experimental) Perl RE features, the [`(??{ code })`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28%3f%3f%7b-code-%7d%29) extended pattern works:

```
$sample =~ s/[+-](\d)(??{ "[a-zA-Z]{$1}" })//g
```

Comment: That is both very cool and frightening at the same time.  Heaven help a maintainer that comes along later and has to figure out what that does.  But that can be said of almost all regex, and even perl in general by some.  (My friends call Perl a write only language).

Comment: It is experimental, but other than that...wow. It certainly isn't your grandfather's regex!

Comment: The URL works when it is spelled: `http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3f%3f%7b-code-%7d)`; it does not work when spelled `http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28%3f%3f%7b-code-%7d%29`. When I entered it, I included the parentheses; SO replaced parentheses with `%28` and `%29`.  I'm not happy about that.

Comment: I reported the URL problem on MSO. It turns out to be a Chrome issue (Firefox is OK with both forms of the URL).  I've reported the issue to the Chrome developers.